# How to find the maximum of a graph

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to label the maximum of the solution to an ODE system. Is there a way I can either label or print the maximum value the curve reaches?

Here is my code for the solutions to the ODE System

```
a=1
d=0.5
g=1
p=2
r=0.5
y0=[0.9,0.01]

def system(y, t, g, r, a, p, d):
    Stem, Non = y
    dydt = [d*(g-r)*(1-(Stem+Non)*(Stem+Non))*Stem, (1-d)*g*(1-(Stem+Non)*(Stem+Non))*Stem-a*Non+(p-r)*(1-(Stem+Non)*(Stem+Non))*Non]
    return dydt

t=np.linspace(0,2,101)
from scipy.integrate import odeint
sol = odeint(system, y0, t, args=(g,r,a,p,d))
max(sol)
argmax(sol)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(t, sol[:,0]+sol[:,1], 'r')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

I am getting the following error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-087c41a3d8b9> in <module>
     15 sol = odeint(system, y0, t, args=(g,r,a,p,d))
     16 
---> 17 max(sol)
     18 argmax(sol)
     19 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/pyplots/annotation_basic.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-annotation-basic-py

Comment: @Julien, isn't this only useful if I already know the maximum of my point and I would like to annotate it? This code I provided is easy to tell where the maximum is, but for my other plots that I have not shown the code for it is not as easy

Comment: huuh, use `max` to find the max? (`argmax`to find the location)

Comment: @Julien, sorry! I misinterpreted the link? I have tried your suggestion and I am a bit stuck on what to do next